# Can nullptr be converted to uintptr_t? Different compilers disagree

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++, clang

Consider this program:

```
#include <cstdint>
using my_time_t = uintptr_t;

int main() {
    const my_time_t t = my_time_t(nullptr);
}
```

It failed to compile with msvc v19.24:

```
<source>(5): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'nullptr' to 'my_time_t'
<source>(5): note: A native nullptr can only be converted to bool or, using reinterpret_cast, to an integral type
<source>(5): error C2789: 't': an object of const-qualified type must be initialized
<source>(5): note: see declaration of 't'

Compiler returned: 2
```

but clang (9.0.1) and gcc (9.2.1) "eat" this code without any errors.

I like the MSVC behaviour, but is it confirmed by standard?
In other words is it bug in clang/gcc or it is possible to interpret
standard that this is right behaviour from gcc/clang?

Comment: I read this as copy initialization from a function-style cast.  That then gets interpreted by the compiler [as one of the C++ casts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) "even if it cannot be compiled".  Maybe there is an inconsistency between compilers as to how the cast gets interpreted

Comment: As far as I am aware MSVC v19.24 does not support a C++11 mode. Did you mean C++14 or C++17 instead?

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion MSVC is not behaving standard-conform.

I am basing this answer on C++17 (draft N4659), but C++14 and C++11 have equivalent wording.

`my_time_t(nullptr)` is a *postfix-expression* and because `my_time_t` is a type and `(nullptr)` is a single expression in a parenthesized initializer list, it is exactly equivalent to an explicit cast expression. ([[expr.type.conv]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.post#expr.type.conv-2))

The explicit cast tries a few different specific C++ casts (with extensions), in particular also `reinterpret_cast`. ([[expr.cast]/4.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.cast#4)) The casts tried before `reinterpret_cast` are `const_cast` and `static_cast` (with extensions and also in combination), but none of these can cast `std::nullptr_t` to an integral type.

But `reinterpret_cast<my_time_t>(nullptr)` should succeed because [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#4) says that a value of type `std::nullptr_t` can be converted to an integral type as if by `reinterpret_cast<my_time_t>((void*)0)`, which is possible because `my_time_t = std::uintptr_t` should be a type large enough to represent all pointer values and under this condition the same standard paragraph allows the conversion of `void*` to an integral type.

It is particularly strange that MSVC does allow the conversion if cast notation rather than functional notation is used:

```
const my_time_t t = (my_time_t)nullptr;
```

Comment: Yep. Note that `static_cast` in particular has some cases intended to trap the C-style cast ladder (e.g., a C-style cast to an ambiguous base is an ill-formed `static_cast` rather than an `reinterpret_cast`), but none applies here.

Comment: `my_time_t(nullptr)` is by definition the same as `(my_time_t)nullptr`, so MSVC is certainly wrong to accept one and reject the other.

Answer (score 2):

Although I can find no **explicit** mention in this [Working Draft C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (from 2014) that conversion from `std::nullptr_t` to an integral type is forbidden, there is also no mention that such a conversion is allowed!

However, the case of conversion from `std::nullptr_t` to `bool` **is** explicitly mentioned:

> **4.12 Boolean conversions**
>  A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member
>   pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to
>   true. For direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the
>   resulting value is false.

Further, the *only* place in this draft document where conversion from `std::nullptr_t` to an integral type is mentioned, is in the "reinterpret_cast" section:

> **5.2.10 Reinterpret cast**
>   ...
>   (4) A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it. The mapping function is
>   implementation-defined. [ Note: It is intended to be unsurprising to
>   those who know the addressing structure of the underlying machine. —
>   end note ] A value of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to an
>   integral type; the conversion has the same meaning and validity as a
>   conversion of (void*)0 to the integral type. [Note: A reinterpret_cast
>   cannot be used to convert a value of any type to the type
>   std::nullptr_t. — end note ]

So, from these two observations, one could (IMHO) *reasonably* surmise that the `MSVC` compiler is correct.

**EDIT**: However, your use of the "functional notation cast" may actually suggest the opposite! The `MSVC` compiler has no problem using a C-style cast in, for example:

```cpp
uintptr_t answer = (uintptr_t)(nullptr);
```

but (as in your code), it complains about this:

```cpp
uintptr_t answer = uintptr_t(nullptr); // error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'nullptr' to 'uintptr_t'
```

Yet, from the same Draft Standard:

> **5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation)**
>   (1) A simple-type-specifier (7.1.6.2) or typename-specifier (14.6) followed
>   by a parenthesized expression-list constructs a value of the specified
>   type given the expression list. If the expression list is a single
>   expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in
>   definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast
>   expression (5.4). ...

The "corresponding cast expression (5.4)" can refer to a C-style cast.

Answer (score 0):

All are standard conformant (ref. draft n4659 for C++).

`nullptr` is defined in [lex.nullptr] as:

> The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. It is a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. [ Note: ..., a prvalue of this type is
>   a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value.]

Even if notes are non normative, this one makes clear that for the standard, `nullptr` is expected to be converted to a null **pointer** value.

We later find in [conv.ptr]:

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal with value zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A
>   null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; .... A null pointer constant of integral type can
>   be converted to a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.

Here again what is required by the standard is that `0` can be converted to a `std::nullptr_t` and that `nullptr` can be converted to any pointer type.

My reading is that the standard has no requirement on whether `nullptr` can be *directly* converted to an integral type or not. From that point on:

- MSVC has a strict reading and forbid the conversion
- Clang and gcc behaves as if an intermediary `void *` conversion was involved.

Comment: I think this is wrong. Some null pointer constants are integer literals with value zero, but `nullptr` isn't because it has the non-integral type `std::nullptr_t`. 0 can be converted to a `std::nullptr_t` value, but not to the literal `nullptr`. This is all intentional, `std::nullptr_t` is a more restricted type to prevent unintended conversions.

Comment: @MSalters: I think that you are right. I wanted to reword it and did it wrong. I have edited my post with your comment. Thank you for your help.